# VB6 comparing only numeric characters in srings

Tags: sql, string, parsing, vb6, numeric

I need to compare phone numbers from a CSV file to phone numbers in an SSMS database in VB6 without using the .Net Library. One may have a number as 555-555-5555 and the other may have the same number as (555) 555-5555 which obviously kicks back as different when strings are compared.
I know I can use for loops and a buffer to pull out only numeric characters like:

```
Public Function PhoneNumberNumeric(PhoneNumberCSV As String) As String
Dim CharNdx As Integer
Dim buffer As String
For CharNdx = 1 To Len(PhoneNumberCSV) Step 1
    If IsNumeric(Mid(PhoneNumberCSV, CharNdx, 1)) Then
        buffer = buffer + Mid(PhoneNumberCSV, CharNdx, 1)
    End If
Next
PhoneNumberNumeric = buffer
End Function
```

but this is expensive. Is there a less expensive way to do this?

Comment: Are the only unwanted characters '(', ')', '-', and ' '?

Comment: What is your DBMS? In oracle it can be easily done with function `translate` (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm). Probably, your DBMS has analogs.

Comment: I'll edit the question. DBMS is SSMS

Comment: Bathsheba, not necessarily, this is an import thread from excel CSVs received from one organization to the SSMS database of the organization I am doing this for so it is up to my software to give the info some TLC. I've run into some interesting cases already and just looked through the current file sent that they were asking about this phone number case with and there are phone numbers with periods in it

Comment: Truth be told, what you've done in VB6 is not expensive at all. You could use the Replace function repeatedly to cull out the undesirable characters but that would be more expensive (again, relatively speaking, since that wouldn't be expensive either). I ran your function 100,000 times in .37 seconds. And btw you don't need "Step 1" since that is implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a bit quicker:

```
Private Function Clean(ByRef Original As String) As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim Char As Long

    Clean = Space$(10)
    For I = 1 To Len(Original)
        Char = AscW(Mid$(Original, I, 1))
        If 48 <= Char And Char <= 57 Then
            J = J + 1
            If J > 10 Then Exit For 'Or raise an exception.
            Mid$(Clean, J, 1) = ChrW$(Char)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

It avoids string concatenation, ANSI conversions, and VBScript-form "pigeon VB" (use of slow Variant functions).